# Nivo slider + php

Tags: php, jquery, nivo-slider

I created a custom cms for a website and trying to make the nivo slider work with my db but im having issues with my while loop. 
im only storing the name of the image in the db and the image itself its in a folder, images are working somewhat but they appear on above the other the the actual slideshow is broken.

my guess is that the title id is breaking it but not sure on how to go from here. any help is appreciated

here is my code:

```
<div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>
<?php 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM slider';
$result = $db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $slideshow = $row['slider_id']; 
    print"
        <img src='images/slider/".$row['image'].".jpg' alt='' title='#htmlcaption'>
        </div>
        <div id='htmlcaption' class='nivo-html-caption '>
        <span>".$row['title'] . "</span>    
        </div> ";
}

?>
<div id='preloader'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `title='#htmlcaption'`

Comment: my bad forgot the = but the slideshow still broken, images appearing one above the other - instead of sliding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$slideshow = $row['slider_id']; 
print"
    <img src='images/slider/".$row['image'].".jpg' alt='' title'#htmlcaption'>
    </div> // ---------------> Here you are closing div slider
    <div id='htmlcaption' class='nivo-html-caption '>// ----> Error
    <span>".$row['title'] . "</span>    
    </div> ";
```

}

In  while loop you are closing `</div>` without opening it,This cause broken slide show.In HTML syntax id's must be unique. So `<div id='htmlcaption' class='nivo-html-caption '>` so change this part.

**[Update]**
change print to

```
 print" <div class='some_wraper'>
        <img src='images/slider/".$row['image'].".jpg' alt='' title='#htmlcaption'>
        </div> // ---------------> Here now you are closing div some_wraper
        <div class='nivo-html-caption htmlcaption'>// ----> added new class htmlcaption
        <span>".$row['title'] . "</span>    
        </div> ";
```

**Update**
Fixed code

```
 <div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>
    <?php 

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM slider';
    $result = $db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

     for($i = 0;$row = $result->fetch_assoc();$i++){
        $slideshow = $row['slider_id']; 
        echo "<img src='images/slider/".$row['image'].".jpg' alt='' title='htmlcaption_$i'>";                
        $tiles[$i]=$row['title'];        
    }

    ?>
    </div>        
   <?php //caption divs for slider
      for($i=0;$i<count($tiles);$i++) {
        echo "<div id='htmlcaption_$i' class='nivo-html-caption '>";      
            echo "<span>".$tiles[$i]."</span> </div>";
        }   
    ?>        
    <div id='preloader'></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry trying to wrap my head around it, fairly new to php, should i close php before the closing div and then reopen it? or just give it a dynamic id ?

Comment: I did this: but still not working:

<img src='images/slider/".$row['image'].".jpg' alt='' title='#".$row['slider_id'] . "'>
     </div>
     <div id='".$row['slider_id'] . "' class='nivo-html-caption '>
     <span>".$row['title'] . "</span> 
     </div> ";

Comment: Try this <div class='some_wrap'>
<img src='images/slider/".$row['image'].".jpg' alt='' title'#htmlcaption'>
    </div>

Comment: the wrapper div kinda work but added a bunch of empty slides and captions stopped displaying, changed the #htmlcaption to .htmlcaption but that didnt seem to work since u changed it to a class

Comment: alt='' title'#htmlcaption'>  this part did you fixed or just copy pasted my code  ? if not fix it. Empty slides are because of your database or files

Comment: yes this is what i added so its unique: image = image name 

`print"
  <div class='nivoSliderWrapper'>
        <img src='images/slider/".$row['image'].".jpg' alt='' title'#".$row['image'] . "'>
        </div> 
        <div id='#".$row['image'] . "' class='nivo-html-caption htmlcaption'>
        <span>".$row['title'] . "</span>    
        </div> ";`

Comment: @SergioWizenfeld I have updated the code, Nivo Slider need another separate div for captions. http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider#jumpNav-3

Comment: That works going over the code trying to understand it, for the captions its appearing multiple for each slide so for slide1 caption for slide 1 and 2 are appearing, im guessing that has to do with the #htmlcaption tag again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47589/discussion-between-shanoop-and-sergio-wizenfeld)